# Unable to save class objects to a SharedObject FIle

Tags: actionscript-3, loading, save, shared-objects

Well basically as the title implies, I can't save my array to the shared object.

I have an array which contains different "soldiers" with different characteristics(Health,Armor,Weapon,Position,Exp,Level) etc etc and was wondering how I would go about saving it. When I reload the swf I get this trace (",,,") but before I reload it I get a correct array reading.

This is my code if it helps:

```
//Saving game
function saveGame(E:MouseEvent){    
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("saveFile"); //Instantiating the shared object

so.data.savedUnitArray = towerDefenceMain.unitArray;// is the array that stores the Soldiers

trace(so.data.savedUnitArray); //returns correct trace
so.flush();//Saving the operation
}


            //Loading the data back
        var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("saveFile");

        if(so.data.savedUnitArray != undefined){
        unitArray = so.data.savedUnitArray;
        trace(unitArray); //returns (",,,,")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to save a custom object, you either have to make all its properties public and accessible, AND have no references to DisplayObjects, or implement `IExternalizable` and define `writeExternal()` and `readExternal()` methods. Note that if your object is read from elsewhere, it first is initialized via zero parameter call to its constructor, and then the instance's `readExternal()` is invoked.

[The manual on IExternalizable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html)

An example:

```
public class Tower2 extends Obstacle implements gameRunnable,IExternalizable {
    // HUGE set of statistics skipped, all methods skipped
    public function writeExternal(output:IDataOutput):void {
    output.writeInt(gemType);
    output.writeInt(gemGrade);
    output.writeBoolean(affectsFlying); // as some gems might be elongated, saving this
    output.writeInt(_targetMode); // placeholder for targetting
    output.writeInt(kills);
    // hehe, what else to write in here? Everything else is derivable
}

public function readExternal(input:IDataInput):void {
    var gt:int = input.readInt();
    var gg:int = input.readInt();
    MakeGem(gt, gg); // this is the function that initializes everything that's the tower
    raised = true; // will place manually if ever
    affectsFlying = input.readBoolean();
    gt = input.readInt();
    SetTargetting(gt);
    kills = input.readInt(); // kills
    updateDamage(); // this updates damage respective to kills counter
}
```

So, for your Soldiers you only need to save essential data, and re-create everything else once you load your set of soldiers from the shared object.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that I should store all the variables in each separate soldier like Health, then recreate a new soldier class and set the class soldier health to the savedHealth in the Shared Object?

Comment: Not exactly. Say your Soldier class has its own variable "health". You write it in your `writeExternal()` via `writeInt()` call, then you read it back in `readExternal()` in a `readInt()` call. The same with all the other variables that you want to be saved. Note that order matters, as those input and output instances don't care of your object's data integrity, you have to maintain it yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help :) I wouldn't have figured it out! Cheers :D